# Delete folder older than 30 minutes with Cron

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I would like to know what job should I insert in Cron so that every **folder** that is older than 30 minutes gets deleted.

I tried that:

```
# 30 * * * * find /path/to/my/folder -type f -mmin +30 -exec rm -fr -maxdepth 0 {} \;
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

There are other posts here on Stackoverflow, but they all talk about removing **files**, which is cool but I also want to remove the folder in itself, as well as its content.

Comment: **where** did you put that stanza (which file)?  Does cron have permission to delete the directory?  What do you see in syslog when cron tries to run this?

Comment: `-type f` actually makes sure that you *don't* touch directories.

Comment: Do you even need `find`? Do you just want to delete `/path/to/my/folder`?

Comment: Check the logfiles for errors, are there any? BTW: Think about why you put a backslash before the semicolon!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any error, when I do `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I see these two last lines: Jan 19 20:30:01 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 CRON[10764]: (root) CMD (find /p2e/public/pyfilesdownload/ -type d -mmin +5 -exec rm -fr -maxdepth 0 {} \;)
Jan 19 20:30:01 ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01 CRON[10763]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: is the "No MTA.." stuff an error?

Comment: @BenjaminW. In my understanding I need to use find to check if the folder is older than 30m or not. I just tried with -type d, didn't change anything

Comment: Huh? Why are you passing `-maxdepth` to your `rm` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found out that the best method is to divide the commands in Cron in 2 parts, and use the `-delete` argument

> Code

```
30 * * * * sudo find /my/folder/* -type f -mmin +30 -delete && sudo find /my/folder/* -type d -empty -mmin +30 -delete
```

> Explanations

`30 * * * *`: execute every 30mn all the time
`sudo find /my/folder/* -type f -mmin +45 -delete` : delete all files and subfiles that are older than 45 minutes
`&&` : do only if first command has successfully run
`sudo find /my/folder/* -type d -empty -mmin +45 -delete` : delete all empty folders that are older than 45 minutes

Working on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

`tmpwatch` (most RedHat distro) package will do.

> DESCRIPTION
>          tmpwatch  recursively  removes  files which haven’t been accessed for a given time.  Normally, it’s used to clean up directories which are used for
>          temporary holding space such as /tmp.

```
tmpwatch -umc 30m --nodirs notThisDir /path/to/directory/ThatIwantToClean
```

More in `man tmpwatch`. This package provides a `cron` example in `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`. You can modify the script to fit to your needs and put the cron in `/etc/cron.hourly/`. Something like the following:

```
 $ cat /usr/local/bin/cleanfolder
 #!/bin/bash

 flags="-umcvv"
 /usr/sbin/tmpwatch "${flags}" 30m /my/folder
```

Change permission:

```
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/cleanfolder
```

In `/etc/cron.d/cleanfolder-cron`, put it like this:

```
30 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/cleanfolder
```

Reload your `cron` service.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, how would I go about installing that on my machine?

Comment: Some quick google search, yields this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/717661/package-for-tmpwatch

Comment: Already tried this one, doesn't work. It can't unzip the downloaded file, it's corrupt

Comment: Try from here, http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/tmpwatch/tmpwatch-2.11.tar.bz2/9ea7e169296eb1196b80fe05bba1cbd0/

Comment: Thanks, with the correct package it correctly installed. Sadly i can't find an example of a cron job with tmpwatch in the directory you specified. Just tried `2 * * * * /usr/sbin/tmpwatch -umc 1m /my/folder;` just to check if it's working, and it's not deleting anything. I also tried `2 * * * * tmpwatch -umc 1m /p2e/uploads;` but it doesn't work. Running that command straight from the console does work tho.

Comment: Did you try with user `root`, something like this:  `2 * * * * root /usr/sbin/tmpwatch ......`

Comment: I just tried that it didn't work. I also tried replacing root with sudo, didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you think about the directory. Then change the **-type f** options to **-type d**

Comment: the correct command is
find . -type d -mmin +30   -exec rm -rf {} \;
It works on Suse Linux.. The directoies and content was deleted

Answer (score -1):

From man pages
...
find . -type d -empty -delete  - Delete all empty directories.
rm - Remove files (rm -rf will recursively remove folders and their contents).

...should do it.